# Add Index for ref field in rxdb

Tags: angular, rxjs, pouchdb

I want to add an index for a reference field in my schema:

```
  persons:                 {
    "type":  "array",
    "ref":   "person",
    "items": {
      "type":  "string",
      "index": true
    }
  }
```

When I try to create a database I get this error:

ERROR RxError: RxError:
SchemaCheck: given index is not defined in schema
Given parameters: {
key:"persons.items"}

How can I define an index for a reference field?